# Combine replace `.compactMap` with custom `.decode`

Tags: swift, decode, combine, publisher

I have created an `AnyPublisher` for subscribing to Firestore documents and the Output type is a DocumentSnapshot.

I run it like this...

```
firestoreSubscription.subscribe(MyHashable(), "/user/1234567890")
    .compactMap { try? $0.data(as: UserDoc.self }
```

The return type of this is `<UserDoc, Never>` which I want to keep.

This worked but I thought it would be cool if I could use the `.decode` function on Publisher to make it a bit more Combiney.

So I created this...

```
public struct FirestoreDecoder: TopLevelDecoder {
    public init() {}
    
    public typealias Input = DocumentSnapshot
    
    public func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from: DocumentSnapshot) throws -> T where T : Decodable {
        try! from.data(as: type)!
    }
}
```

So now I try this...

```
environment.firestoreSubscription.subscribe(userSubscriptionID, "/user/\(state.userID)")
    .decode(type: UserDoc.self, decoder: FirestoreDecoder())
```

But... `TopLevelDecoder` throws rather than returning `nil`. I wonder, is it possible to throw away the throws and default back to my compact map solution that I had whilst using the `.decode` method?

Or... should I just keep using the `.compactMap`?

Also... will the `throw` on the `.decode` end the publisher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, by changing the `FirestoreDecoder` to this...

```
import Firebase

public struct FirestoreDecoder {
    public static func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> (DocumentSnapshot) -> T? where T: Decodable {{
        try? $0.data(as: type)
    }}
}
```

I was able to do...

```
firestoreSubscription.subscribe(MyHashable(), "/user/1234567890")
    .compactMap(FirestoreDecoder.decode(UserDoc.self))
```

Which is similar to what I had in the first place but pushes the dependency on `Firestore` out to the separate module.

Answer (score 1):

> will the throw on the .decode end the publisher

Yes, this will result a failure in the stream - if you are subscribing to changes on Firestore this is probably not what you want

You can use the [`catch`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anypublisher/catch(_:)#) operator of Combine to handle a failure in the stream

Using your example, to ignore a failure you would catch and return an [`Empty`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/empty#) publisher.

```
environment.firestoreSubscription.subscribe(userSubscriptionID, "/user/\(state.userID)")
    .decode(type: UserDoc.self, decoder: FirestoreDecoder())
    .catch{ _ in Empty<UserDoc, Never>().eraseToAnyPublisher() }
```

Comment: Fancy seeing you here. LOL!

Comment: In the end I changed the FirestoreDecoder so I could do... `.compactMap(FirestoreDecoder.decode(UserDoc.self))` 